# OCaml, Sync on two events simultaneous with "and"

Tags: multithreading, events, synchronization, ocaml

I wrote an short program with 6 threads and 3 channels. 3 Threads are sending on 2 channels simultaneous and the other 3 are receiving. The problem is now, that it seems, that a sending thread takes one channel, but if it can't take the second one, it keeps the first.
I would like to have the effect, that a sending thread tries to send over 2 channels. If this doesn't work, it doesn't reserve the one it gets and waits for the last to work on.

I thought this would do it. But it seems not.

```
let takeFork2 = Event.send take_f2 3 in
let takeFork3 = Event.send take_f3 3 in
let e2 = Event.sync takeFork2 and
e3 = Event.sync takeFork3 in
```

So the **and** is misleading here?! Should I use a nested wrap, wrap_abort, choose, ... to get my goal?

I asked this to get the **and** known. I am not familiar with OCaml.

Thanks

Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `and` is not an event primitive. It’s a fundamental piece of OCaml syntax whose purpose is to allow mutually recursive definitions. It seems to me it’s not misleading as long as you’re aware of this. If it were an event primitive it would be defined in the `Event` module, it seems to me.

As far as I can see the `Event` module doesn’t support waiting on the conjunction of events, only on the disjunction. Waiting on conjunctions seems (to me) to be prone to deadlocks.